# Media query not working for ipad

Tags: css, ipad

Hi I wrote media query to have responsive view of navbar in ipad. My media query is not working.

```
 .nav-tabs>li>a {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .nav-tabs>li>a {
        color: #2b2b2b;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 26px;
        padding: 4px 12px;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

**device-width** and **device-height** are both deprecated media features, you should use **max(/min)-device-width** and **max(/min)-device-height** instead.

You can check the list of available media features here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/) at CSS-tricks wrote a really good - slightly outdated - [reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for almost all devices. The code below relates to I-pads and how to specifically target them with CSS.

```css
/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 /* -- style goes here -- */
}
```

Comment: @ashworx in that case the issue might be something different. Is it a live website?

Comment: It might help if your provide a link to it or the rest of your relevant code.